# Sequelize - define model with a select instead of a tableName

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Currently, Sequelize lets you define a model specifying a tableName. But instead of defining it with a table, I wanted to do something like this:

tableName: `'(SELECT * FROM my_table)'`

But that's not possible because sequelize puts quotes on that. So the value is not treated as literal. I'm using mySQL.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: why you really need to do like this. can you please explain use case. so anyone here could understand and help you out.

Comment: How about creating a VIEW?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the initialization into 2 stages.

1. Init TableNameModel.
2. Select all table names.
3. Init other models.

But it is better not to do so, create a constants file and take the table name from there.